# vbscript - XHTML image in table

Tags: html, vba, vbscript, outlook, background-image

I am actually working on a vbscript to generate an Outlook signature using HTML and so far so good.
However, when I am trying to add an image as background in the HTML, the image would not show up.
Find my code below;

```
'-HTML signature
htmlFilePath = pathToCopyTo & "Signature.htm"
Set htmlFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(htmlFilePath, TRUE)
htmlfile.WriteLine("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0Transitional//EN""""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"">")
htmlfile.WriteLine("<html xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"" >") 
htmlfile.WriteLine("<body>") 
htmlfile.WriteLine("<div><table background=""C:\Logon\backG.jpg""><tr><td>")
htmlfile.WriteLine("<div style="" font-size:18pt;color:'RGB(15,0,250)';font-family:'Forte';"">" & strFirstName & " " &  strLastName & "</div>")
htmlfile.WriteLine("<div style="" font-size:12pt;font-family:'Arial';"">" & strTitle & "</div>") 
htmlfile.WriteLine("<div style="" font-size:8pt;font-family:'Arial';"">" & Details & "</div>")   
htmlfile.WriteLine("</td></tr></table></div>")

htmlfile.WriteLine("<div><table><tr><td style=""width:70%"">")
htmlfile.WriteLine("<img src=""C:\Logon\pix.jpg"">")
htmlfile.WriteLine("</td><td>")
htmlfile.WriteLine("<img src=""C:\Logon\logo.jpg"">")
htmlfile.WriteLine("</td></tr></table></div>")

htmlfile.WriteLine("</body>")
htmlfile.Write("</html>")
```

The same html was constructed separately and launched through internet explorer and it shows up correctly.

I can't figure out why `<table background=""C:\Logon\backG.jpg"">` would not work, even if I put it as a body attribute or td, the image just doesn't show up. The other images are displayed correctly, only for the `background` which is not showing up.

Any idea guys?

Comment: Did you test with another image, like <table background=""C:\Logon\logo.jpg""> for instance ?

Comment: Yes but in vain. however, if I change `background` to `bg-color` and set a colour, it works.

Comment: Test question: How do you suppose would an image with a source of `"C:\something"` work in the e-mail client at the receiving end?

Comment: @Tomalak the images would be on a server, I am only performing the test on my local pc, then change the image upon deployment!. thnx

Answer (score 0):

Outlook uses Word as an email editor. You can read about supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the following articles in MSDN:

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338200%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

You need to upload the image on any web server or add it as an attachment. In case of hidden attachments you need to use the cid value. Set PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID property (DASL - http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F) on the attachment using Attachment.PropertyAccessor. Be aware, the PropertyAccessor property of the Attachment class was added in Outlook 2007.

You may find the [How do I embed image in Outlook Message in VBA?](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/re-do-embed-image-outlook-message-vba-t3695969.html) link helpful.